# Fixing Internet Explorer 8/9 (only) Width Issues for display: IDs/Classes recognized by CSS but not functioning properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, e-commerce

this is my first battle with 'correcting' display issues with CSS in IE8/9. Looks fine in Chrome/FF. Slowly making my way through the form but stuck at this spot.

[image: ie issues]

This has been a funky challenge so far as there have been spots I have had to use margin where I would normally use pattern, so on so on. The app is in RoR 3.0.7, Mac OS X Lion.

Using Virtual Box and had to download the IE 8/9 stuff. Kinda sucks bc I can't maximize the screen. Anyways.

I've tried padding and margin values of zero, negatives, positives, widths. I CANNOT get these damn things on the same line, let alone change their widths whatsoever!

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `position:relative`, reset `margin` and `padding`, try `left:10px`, also `display:block;`. Add `width:` and `height` too. Should work than.

Comment: Of course display block :) And have tried widths, both percentage and pixels. Not working.

Comment: Maybe `position:absolute` as last resort, plus `top:` for each field ?

Comment: than the only thing you should worry is the width of container, leave your entries without `width`, or with `width:auto`/`width:100%` - but you tried that I guess. Can't help you than :/

Answer (score 0):

Got it...I'm an idiot, or a noob, or both. I didn't have a container for all the words. Swear I tried it last night but didn't work. Just made a container and set the width and good to go!